# IF multiple no funciona

Tags: c

He probado esto y siempre funciona introduzca la cifra que sea

```
if(i==(1|2|3|4|5)){

    printf("me ha llegado un numero del 1 al 5");
 }
```

alternativas??

Comment: Prueba con `if( ( i > 0 ) && ( i < 6 ) ) { ...`

Comment: Creo que lo que pretendias (no siendo para nada optimo) era if (i==1 || i==2 || i==3...

Comment: -1. No es justo preguntar por alternativas cuando no se ha [buscado](http://isearchnotes.com/single.php?id=318) lo suficiente al respecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` es el operador **bitwise or**.

Esto significa que coge los dos operandos y hace el **or binario, bit a bit**. Asi, `1|2` es `0001|0010` que devuelve `0011` (o sea 3).

Además, aparte de la precedencia de los operadores, primero haces el `|` de todos los números (que devuelve `7` y despues comparas el resultado con `i`).

Como han sugerido los comentarios, para comprobar que un entero está en un rango de números lo más habitual es comprobar que es mayor o igual que el límite inferior del rango y que también es menor o igual que el límite superior del rango, es decir:

```
if ((i >= 1) && (i <= 5))
```

En caso de que la lista de números no sea correlativa, se puede use la construcción `switch-case`:

```
switch (i) {
  case 1:
    // No se pone break para que no salte
  case 3:
  case 4:
    ... Aquí es 1, 3, ó 4
    break;
  default:
    ... Aquí no es 1, 3 ni 4.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz el if así

```
if( i==1 || i==2 || i==3 || i==4 || i==5 )){
    printf("me ha llegado un numero del 1 al 5");
 }else{
    printf("número no encontrado")
 }
```

la otra opción es que uses un switch para cada caso del 1 al 5 y un default (todo el rango de números diferentes a los establecidos en los casos) que indique que el número ingresado no es válido.

Answer (score -2):

Cualquier numero que ingrese, distinto de cero va a entrar al IF. La comprobación que esta haciendo tu código es evaluar true o true o true o true o true igual a true contra i entonces cualquier numero distinto de cero es true y por lo tanto entra. Prueba con if(i >=1 && i <=5). Espero te sirva.

Comment: No, para nada (en cuanto a la explicación de lo que está haciendo su código): https://ideone.com/Aqv6em. -1

Comment: Una aclaración: `1|2|3|4|5 = 0001 | 0010 | 0011 | 0100 | 0101 = 0111 = 7`. Esto invalida completamente tu explicación. Considera editarla para que pueda ser una respuesta válida.